# Keep getting an error insert Variable Declaration to complete VariableDeclaration on my Java program

Tags: java, variables, error-handling, declaration

Keeping getting errors and I am new to Java. I keep getting errors about Variable Declaration needed. Advice?

```
    public class Trying 
    {

        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {   

            nestedFor;
            int i =0;



        }



            public static void nestedFor(int) 
            {
                int i = 0; 
                int h =0;
                for (int = i; i<=4; i++)
                    for (int = h; i <=6; h++)
                        System.out.println ("Testing 1,2,3");
            }
}
```

Comment: Please correct your code (`public class Trying {`)

Comment: If you are new to Java you should learn from books, tutorials or more experienced colleagues not by posting questions on SO. If you take any Java book and look for "Method declaration" or "Method arguments" you will see the problem immediately.

Comment: nestedFor should be `nestedFor();` and `for (int = i; i<=4; i++)` should be `for (i = 0; i<=4; i++)`

Answer (score 0):

If you mean showing "Testing 1,2,3" 5×7=35 times, your code should look like this:

```
    public class Trying 
    {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {   
        nestedFor();
    }

    public static void nestedFor() 
    {
            int i = 0; 
            int h =0;
            for (i=0; i<=4; i++)
                for (h=0; h <=6; h++)
                    System.out.println ("Testing 1,2,3");
    }
    }
```